# Manipular los checkbox de un grid con Knockoutjs y KendoUI

Tags: javascript, kendoui, knockoutjs

Quisiera saber cómo detectar el cambio en la propiedad de un objeto observable en una grilla al seleccionar un checkbox con knockoutjs.
El código que actualmente  tengo es de esta forma.

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid:{data: asignados, columns:columns}"></div>

<script type="text/javascript>
var RecursosVm = function () {
var self = this;
self.columns = [
    {
        title   : "",
        field   : "isChecked",
        template: "<input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: checkedAlert'/>"
    },
    { title: "Código", field: "reC_CLIENTKEY" },
    { title: "Nombre", field: "reC_NOMBRE_COMPLETO" }
];
self.asignados = ko.observableArray([]);
self.disponibles = ko.observableArray([]);
self.checkedAlert = function() {
    //aqui deberia capturar el objeto
};
self.moverDisponibles = function() {
   //TODO:
}}
```

El problema es que al seleccionar el checkbox no cambia el valor del objeto ni dispara la función y de allí no hay forma de recuperar los objetos seleccionados.

Comment: ¿Qué es una grilla? lo siento pero grilla es polítiquería en el castellano que se habla en México

Comment: @Ruslan, parece que tendremos que acostumbrarnos con el español informatico internacional ;) Tampoco lo sé pero supongo que es *grid*

Answer (score 4):

El `checked` binding requiere un `boolean` o un `observable` de boolean para bindearlo al html

Si necesitas ejecutar una funcion al cambiar el valor del checkbox en la UI puedes crear un [Writable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) para tal fin

```
self._checkbox = ko.observable(false); //o el valor por defecto que necesites
self.checkedAlert = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return this._checkbox();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        //TODO: Acá va lo que quieres ejecutar cuando se cambia el valor del checkbox
        this._checkbox(value);
    },
    owner: self
});
```

Comment: El que votó en contra se puede dignar de explicar?

Comment: No entiendo por qué votan en contra, la respuesta no me parece para nada mala. Estamos en beta privada, no deberían de pasar estas cosas. Voto a favor para eliminar el efecto negativo del -1 y porque me parece una buena respuesta.

Comment: Lo más natural para este caso es usar el método `<observable>.subscribe(function (value) {})` o plantearse: _¿cuál es el motivo para engancharse al evento checked?_ Es muy probable que el problema se pueda expresar ampliando el modelo con un computed con un sentido lógico. El computed que planteas, Carlos, no tiene un sentido diferente al propio valor del checked (el contra ejemplo sería el caso b) en mi respuesta).

Answer (score 2):

## Problema y solución

Has confundido un **evento** de tipo *checked* con el **enlace a datos** o **binding** de tipo **checked**. El binding de Knockout requiere una expresión de tipo *Observable* o un valor estático, no una función que gestiona un evento.

```
<input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: <expresión>'/>
```

En este caso has de definir un **observable** para cada *recurso* que represente el estado de *estar seleccionado* y enlazar la interfaz con él:

```
...
self.isChecked = ko.observable(valorInicial);
...

<input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: isChecked'/>
```

Dependiendo de lo que debas hacer cuando se alterne el checkbox, puede tener sentido subscribirte al cambio (a) o ampliar tu modelo con un *computed* que dependa de los distintos observables isChecked, si esto encaja en tus necesidades. Por ejemplo:

#### a) Método subscribe

```
self.isChecked.subscribe(function (value) {
    // Ojo: se dispara siempre al cambiar de estado...
    console.log((value ? 'seleccionado' : 'deseleccionado') + '(' + self.clave() + ')');
    // Salida: 
    // seleccionado(123)       // Al seleccionar
    // deseleccionado(123)     // Al deseleccionar
});
```

#### b) Computed

```
// Si queremos mostrar cuántos recursos están seleccionados
self.numSeleccionados = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.asignados().filter(function (e) {
            return e.isChecked();
        }).length;
});
```

## Ejemplo:

En este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7st4pkz7/2/) hay un ejemplo concreto.

#### Nota:

Realmente, la utilización del **KendoGrid** o un *foreach* de **Knockout** es indiferente en este caso.